# How to get the music folder path in xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, special-folders

I'm trying to save a mp3 file, into the device's music library folder.(I Want it to show up immediately as a playable song).
More clearly i'm looking for the path `/storage/emulated/0/Music/`, in each phone.Im not sure if this path changes, so i would rather not take the risk.

I have tried this paths:

- `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonMusic -> Blank`
- `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic -> /data/user/0/App.App/files/Music`
- `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic -> /Music`

None of this offer, what i wanted.I tried writing to the `/storage/emulated/0/Music/` which did the job, but i dont think this path is stable.

Anyone knows how can i get the music folder path programmatically ? Im coding in C# using xamarin.android.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to get access to my Music Folder

```
public void StartPlayer(String filePath)
    {

     string Mp3Path = Path.Combine("/sdcard/"+
 Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic,
    filePath);
        if (player == null)
        {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
        }

            player.Reset();
            player.SetDataSource(Mp3Path);
            player.Prepare();
            player.Start();

    }
```

The sdcard shortcut works great for me, hope it works for you too ^^